# is there other faster way of doing this

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, vba

below code does the following: it takes a range, then finds distinct values in a range,
and stores them in a d_distinct array, also for every distinct value it creates the distinct color, then using the Excel.FormatCondition it colors the range... (my current range is A1:HM232)

```
for (int t = 0; t < d_distinct.Length; t++ )
{                        
    Excel.FormatCondition cond =
        (Excel.FormatCondition)range.FormatConditions.Add(
        Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
        Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, 
        "="+d_distinct[t],
        mis, mis, mis, mis, mis);
    cond.Interior.PatternColorIndex = 
        Excel.Constants.xlAutomatic;
    cond.Interior.TintAndShade = 0;
    cond.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(c[t]);
    cond.StopIfTrue = false;                        
}
```

But this works too slow... user will have to sit and wait for about a minute... I did this with this way since, otherwise if I do it with one line of code simply doing this (which colors amazingly fast)

```
range.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(3);
```

I will not be able to request the color of the cell... (i can have more than ten distinct values in a range)

can you help me to make my first way work faster? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try turning off screen updating while the code is running and turn it back on afterwards. In VBA, that would be:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
// do stuff
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

As you are not using VBA, try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._application.screenupdating(office.11).aspx for guidance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the OpenXML SDK to work with Office 2007?  I have used it for word and found it much faster than using vba or COM.  Try [version 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en) or [1.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=AD0B72FB-4A1D-4C52-BDB5-7DD7E816D046&displaylang=en).  I think 2.0 is still CTP though.  Much more intuitive than vba in my book though.  Otherwise, the screenupdating trick is probably the easiest thing to do.